# json api doesnt return any results in jquery getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm trying to pull info from [**this sample JSON file**](http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getcategory) in their company API documentation. But it's not returning any results :(

**http://jsfiddle.net/28hEb/21/**

```
$.getJSON("http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getcategory", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.category).appendTo("#content");
        if (index == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your fiddle is working for me..

Comment: @BeNdErR which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome! it tooks like 30 secs for the fiddle to load, but then the results were there

Comment: @BeNdErR you probably clicked Kevin's working fiddle :D

Comment: nope.. I clicked yours (and I'm sure of that) twice and it works! Maybe I'm in the matrix and I'm neo.. :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40650/discussion-between-hasan-alaca-and-benderr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `?callback` to the url so that getJSON performs jsonp request rather than ajax/cors/json.

```
http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getcategory?callback=?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/28hEb/22/

Comment: `JSONp` is something else entirely. If the API supports cross origin requests a regular AJAX request should also work.

Comment: Right, but it obviously doesn't support cors, hence why his original attempt didn't work.

Comment: It's likely that it doesn't, but did you check? I'm not familiar with 8coupons.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `callback parameter` for different domain,

```
$.getJSON("http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getcategory?callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.category).appendTo("#content");
        if (index == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Also** read the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy)